# How can I allocate UIImageView dynamically in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to add number of images from library to a view. The number we want to add to the view is not known. How can I allocate UIImageViews dynamically. And I also want to drag those imageviews on the UIView. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'question' consists of way too many parts (the dragging is a different question entirely, one I advice you to look up on Google). And the adding part is easy. The hard part is; where are you getting those images from? Assuming you have an array with image names, it would be something like this;

```
for( NSString *imageName in (NSArray *)imageNames )
{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

  // .. you might want to set a frame to your imageView .. //

  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
  [imageView release];
}
```

Of course, this is not what you want, but with the little information provided, it was the best I could do with my spare time.

Comment: With this I'm able to add number of images to my view . but all the images are adding to a fixed frame. I want to drag those images and I want to place them as I wish. Please help me

Comment: Google's first few hits came up with this -- http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/